# ESLint errors not reflecting in VS Code IDE

Tags: eslint

Heres my eslint.rc :

```
{
"parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": [
    "eslint-config-airbnb",
  ],
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "rules": {
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "arrow-body-style": 0,
    "no-console": 2,
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "react/no-array-index-key": 1,
    "react/prefer-stateless-function": 1,
    "react/require-default-props": 0,
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "template-curly-spacing" : "off",
    "indent": [
      "error", 2,
      { "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral"] }
    ],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js"] }],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": [
      "error",
      {
        "devDependencies": [
          "**/__tests__/**",
          "**/*.spec.*",
          "**/fixtures/**",
          "**/*.stories*",
          "**/scripts/**",
          "./config/**"
        ],
        "optionalDependencies": false
      }
    ],
    "require-jsdoc": ["error", {
      "require": {
        "FunctionDeclaration": true,
        "MethodDefinition": true,
        "ClassDeclaration": true,
        "ArrowFunctionExpression": true
      }
    }],
    "valid-jsdoc": ["error", {
      "prefer": { "arg": "param", "argument": "param", "class": "constructor", "return": "returns", "virtual": "abstract" },
      "preferType": { "Boolean": "boolean", "Number": "number", "object": "Object", "String": "string", "node": "Node" },
      "requireReturn": false,
      "requireReturnType": true,
      "matchDescription": ".+",
      "requireParamDescription": true,
      "requireReturnDescription": false
    }]
  },
  "globals": {
    "window": true,
    "document": true
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".android.js", ".ios.js", ".web.js"]
      }
    }
  },
  "root": true
}
```

heres package.json :

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "1",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "xyz",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "cp-cli build _site/metronic/preview/react && serve",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint --config .eslintrc 'src/**/*.js' --ignore-pattern 'src/**/*.spec.js'",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,css,scss,html}\"",
    "rtl": "webpack"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "last 1 edge version",
      "IE 11"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.11",
    "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^1.3.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.10",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.8",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.6.0",
    "@tanem/svg-injector": "^8.0.35",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.17.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "clipboard-copy": "^3.1.0",
    "clsx": "^1.0.4",
    "cp-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "css-mediaquery": "^0.1.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.8.1",
    "dentist": "^1.0.3",
    "downshift": "^3.4.2",
    "fg-loadcss": "^2.1.0",
    "formik": "^2.0.6",
    "json2mq": "^0.2.0",
    "jss-rtl": "^0.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^1.4.1",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-draggable": "^4.1.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
    "react-highlight": "^0.12.0",
    "react-intl": "^3.6.2",
    "react-is": "^16.12.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-last-location": "^2.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-swipeable-views": "0.13.3",
    "react-swipeable-views-utils": "0.13.3",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^11.0.2",
    "react-window": "^1.8.5",
    "reactstrap": "^8.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-webpack-alias": "^2.1.2",
    "copyfiles": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "7.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "16.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.12.1",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "serve": "^11.2.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Though yarn lint is working; There's an error in eslint task runner -

TypeError: createRequire is not a function
Referenced from: /Users/xyz/Documents/abc/.eslintrc
    at Object.resolve (/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/node_modules/eslint/lib/shared/relative-module-resolver.js:28:20)
at ConfigArrayFactory._loadExtendedShareableConfig (/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array-factory.js:854:39)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._loadExtends (/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array-factory.js:763:25)
    at ConfigArrayFactory._normalizeObjectConfigDataBody (/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array-factory.js:702:25)
    at _normalizeObjectConfigDataBody.next ()
    at ConfigArrayFactory._normalizeObjectConfigData (/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array-factory.js:647:20)
    at _normalizeObjectConfigData.next ()
    at ConfigArrayFactory.loadInDirectory (/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/config-array-factory.js:495:28)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigInAncestors (/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:355:46)
    at CascadingConfigArrayFactory._loadConfigInAncestors (/Users/xyz/Documents/abc/node_modules/eslint/lib/cli-engine/cascading-config-array-factory.js:374:20)